# Deploying Spring Integration to WebSphere ND 8.5.5

Tags: jms, spring-integration, websphere

I am looking for some guidance on deploying a simple Spring Integration application to WebSphere.  The overall scope of the application is quite simple - it reads from a RabbitMQ endpoint, transforms any messages received to a specific xml format, and then posts the message to a JMS endpoint in WAS.

Initially, I built the application as a JAR.  I was able to get it to work well enough with SSL turned off on the IIOP endpoints in WAS, but despite hours of debugging I never could get it to communicate properly with WAS over SSL.  The initial handshake and communication with the bootstrap port was successful, but the SIB endpoint rejected the exact same certificate chain with the usual PKIX chaining error, and no amount of certificate importing made any difference.

So I elected to work out deploying the application as a web app into WAS itself, which would have been the end goal anyways.  This caused a number of issues that i've had to work through:

1. I have not gotten properties to work in the normal Spring fashion.  I assume that in this context Spring needs to be explicitly told where to look, but i've sidestepped this with hardcoding for now. Perhaps using @Resource annotations would be the way to do this in this context?
2. Various jar versioning issues, which i've mostly worked out by setting the application classloader as PARENT_LAST, and judiciously removing things that seemed redundant.
3. Oddly I did have to add some jars related to Parameter validation which don't seem to have been present in my original maven build.
4. Needing to set some values in the web.xml in order for spring to location configuration beans, specifically setting init-param with contextClass (org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext) and contextConfigLocation set to a list of the objects that would normally be loaded via the @Configuration annotation.
5. May or may not be necessary but I did move from Maven to IID in order to hopefully avoid versioning issues with IBM related jars.

Now I would like to know if there are other items generally needed to be done to deploy Spring (especially Spring Integration) to WAS, and whether the above seems like enough.

In addition, I have an issue with the actual JMS connection to WAS. I have tried to use the UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter, and was successful with this with Spring standalone.  However when deployed in WAS, an exception is thrown:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsManagedQueueConnectionFactoryImpl incompatible with javax.jms.ConnectionFactory

I believe this is thrown when the setTargetConnectionFactory method is called, since if I use the connection factory without the UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter, it works fine, except the connection by "anonymous" is rejected by the bus:

> [03/03/21 15:23:32:934 EST] 0000016c SibMessage    W   [BPM.WorkflowServer.Bus:Node1.server1-BPM.WorkflowServer.Bus] CWSII0212W: The bus BPM.WorkflowServer.Bus denied an anonymous user access to the bus.

If you want to see the code, this works fine (but doesn't authenticate):

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() throws NamingException {

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
    Context ctx = null;
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
    p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
    p.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
    p.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,jmsUsername);
    p.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,jmsPassword);

    ctx = new InitialContext(p);

    if (null != ctx)
        System.out.println("Got naming context");

    connectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory");

    if (null != connectionFactory)
        System.out.println("Got connection factory");

    return connectionFactory;

}
```

Whereas this throws the class cast exception:

```
@Bean
public UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter jmsConnectionFactory() throws NamingException {

        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
        Context ctx = null;
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
        p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
        p.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
        p.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,jmsUsername);
        p.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,jmsPassword);

        ctx = new InitialContext(p);

        if (null != ctx)
            System.out.println("Got naming context");

        connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory");

        if (null != connectionFactory)
            System.out.println("Got connection factory");

        UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter adapter = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
        adapter.setTargetConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        adapter.setUsername(jmsUsername);
        adapter.setPassword(jmsPassword);
        return adapter;

        // return connectionFactory;

    }
```

Note: the credentials set in the Context properties seem to have no effect.

I am using this connection factory with Spring Integration Java DSL:

```
            .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(jmsConfig.jmsConnectionFactory())
                    .destination(jmsDestination))
```

I understand from WebSphere documentation that supplying credentials happens on the ConnectionFactory.getConnection() call.  So I wonder whether there is any hook in the DSL where I could override the getConnection so as to provide parameters and avoid the class cast exception that I am seeing.

Alternately I am considering just explicitly calling jms template methods to send the message using a lambda in the handler and creating the connection manually.

So, finally what I would like to ask for is:

- Any overall guidance on deploying a Spring application to WebSphere traditional
- What may be causing the class cast exception

ps, I have placed all of the spring, et al jars in a shared library.  This is the contents:

```
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/accessors-smart-1.2.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/amqp-client-5.10.0.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/asm-5.0.4.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/assertj-core-3.18.1.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/byte-buddy-1.10.19.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/byte-buddy-agent-1.10.19.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/hamcrest-2.2.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/hamcrest-core-2.2.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/hamcrest-library-2.2.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/http-client-3.8.0.RELEASE.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/jackson-annotations-2.11.4.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/jackson-core-2.11.4.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.11.4.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.11.4.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.11.4.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.11.4.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.11.4.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/jakarta.el-3.0.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/json-path-2.4.0.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/json-smart-2.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/jsonassert-1.5.0.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/objenesis-3.1.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/reactor-core-3.4.2.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/snakeyaml-1.27.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-amqp-2.3.4.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-aop-5.3.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-beans-5.3.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-boot-2.4.2.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-boot-starter-2.4.2.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-boot-starter-amqp-2.4.2.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-boot-starter-json-2.4.2.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.4.2.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-boot-starter-web-2.4.2.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-context-5.3.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-core-5.3.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-expression-5.3.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-integration-amqp-5.4.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-integration-core-5.4.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-integration-jms-5.4.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-integration-xml-5.4.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-jcl-5.3.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-jms-5.3.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-messaging-5.3.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-oxm-5.3.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-rabbit-2.3.4.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-rabbit-junit-2.3.4.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-retry-1.3.1.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-tx-5.3.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-web-5.3.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/spring-xml-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/stax2-api-4.2.1.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/woodstox-core-6.2.4.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/xmlunit-core-2.7.0.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/hibernate-validator-6.1.7.Final.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/classmate-1.5.1.jar
c:/IBM/IID/sharedlibs/spring/javax.jms-api-2.0.1.jar
```

UPDATE

So what I finally realized is that:

1. WAS 8.5.5 is using J2EE v6, which means JMS 1.1
2. Spring JMS is using JMS 2.0
3. When I switched to using the UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter, this tries to use the JmsContext interface which is part of JMS 2.0 classes, and not provided by the WAS jee container, so this was the reason for the class cast exception.

What I did was to do the JMS sending manually instead of using any spring integration gateway.  A better solution might be to create my own adapter that extends connection factory and uses credentials in the connect method, but this works well enough for now:

```
.handle( m -> { 
        try {
            jmsConfig.sendMessage( m.getPayload().toString() );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     } )
```

JmsConfig being a bean that manages the connection.

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking for the proper object in JNDI? Feels like this `ctx.lookup("javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory")` is about an attempt to take by class, not name... Anyway it is better to consult with IBM how to deploy Spring apps into WebSphere properly. Seeing a Spring Boot, I would say that you even don't need to deploy into WS: just have it stand alone and connect to its JMS via JNDI. You probably still need to have IBM JMS jars in classpath anyway...

Comment: Actually that is the actual jndi name of the connection factory.

Comment: OK. So, that JNDI object is not a JMS one. Reconsider your WS MQ configuration to bridge it to JMS.

Comment: I am not using MQ